# Does photorec work on non-encrypted APFS?

Tags: apfs, data-recovery, hdd

I have an Ubuntu live USB with testdisk installed on it. I would like to recover data from the HDD of a Macbook Pro using photorec.

The HDD is not encrypted: can photorec recover data from non-encrypted APFS? If not is there any tool that can?

I am asking because in some forums it says that photorec works on non-encrypted APFS but not on encrypted ones while others that it does not work at all with APFS.

Comment: Unless things have changed, I believe that by default Linux cannot mount an **APFS** volume. You will need to add additional software to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find the response of the developer : https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=10142

It's seem ok for non encrypted APFS volumes.